# Derivative with respect to vector

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

I want to calculate the following derivative

$\frac{\partial(\textbf{x}^2)^T\textbf{b}-\textbf{c}^T\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}, \quad \textbf{x},\textbf{b},\textbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (column vectors)

it must be something like the following

$-\textbf{c}+\frac{\partial(\textbf{x}^2)^T\textbf{b}}{\partial \textbf{x}}.$

If I calculate this for a specific example i get this element wise solution

$\begin{bmatrix}
-c_1\\
\vdots\\
-c_n
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
2 x_1 b_1\\
\vdots\\
2 x_n b_n
\end{bmatrix}$.

Is there a way to write the above as a matrix/vector operation, specifically the last term?

Comment: What is the inverse of a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by components

$$
f({\bf x}) = \sum_i x_i^2b_i - c_i x_i
$$

So that

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \sum_i2x_i\delta_{ij}b_i -c_i\delta_{ij}
 = 2x_jb_j - c_j \equiv \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial {\bf x}}\right)_j
$$

In matrix form

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial {\bf x}} = \left(\begin{array}{c} 2x_1b_1 -
 c_1 \\ 2x_2b_2 - c_2 \\ \vdots \\ 2x_nb_n - c_n \end{array}\right)
$$

You can then express this as

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial {\bf x}} = 2
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
b_1 & & & \\ 
& b_2 & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & b_n 
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} 
x_1 \\  x_2 \\ \vdots \\  x_n 
\end{array}\right) - 
\left(\begin{array}{c} 
c_1 \\  c_2 \\ \vdots \\  c_n 
\end{array}\right) = 2{\rm diag}({\bf b})^T {\bf x} - {\bf c}
$$

Comment: Thanks but i already know this. I basically want a way to represent the last term in my last equation

Comment: @OhmSweetOhm You mean the $2xb$ terms?

Comment: Yes. I have found two ways to represent this elemtwise multiplication

Comment: @OhmSweetOhm I updated my answer